# Excel calculate running count ID, if order ID different

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, countif

I want to count the occurrence of each ID as a running total, but where the Order ID is different.

Example sample of table:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Aim:

[image]

I've tried the suggestion of

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,"<>"&B2)+1
```

however, I've found I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Just use IF. Formula in cell C2:

```
=IF(A2<>A1;1;IF(B2=B1;C1;1+C1))
```

Drag down. Notice this will work only if the data is sortered like in your image

Comment: Yes, nice. And for unstructured data one could try `=COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,"<>"&B2)+1`

Comment: It's giving me an error for =IF(A2<>A1;1;IF(B2=B1;C1;1+C1))

Comment: @JvdV for yours it's counting if they are the same but then skipping e.g 1,1,3,4,4,6

Comment: @CodeBob try the formula replacing `;` with commas